# Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension, and am facing an issue:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined".

I am sending XML request to gapi. It is loaded, but while using `gapi.auth2.authorize` function, it gives the above error.

I am new to this and would like to know if I am doing anything wrong, or ways to proceed with it successfully.

background.js

```
var CLIENT_ID = "139751156265-mvroahocc1d4g7e848q44f1uqk0e78mc.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var SCOPES = [
  'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  'https://docs.google.com/feeds'
];
var x;

xhrWithAuth();

function xhrWithAuth() {
  console.log("xhrWithAuth");
  var access_token;
  var retry = true;
  getToken();

  function getToken() {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
      'interactive': true
    }, function(token) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !token) {
        console.log('getAuthToken', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        // callback(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        return;
      }
      console.log(token);
      x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.open('GET', 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js');
      x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      x.onload = function() {
        console.log(x.response);
      };
      x.send();
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.gapi_onload = checkAuth(token, x);
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
};

function checkAuth(test, x) {
  console.log("inside checkAuth", new Date());
  gapi.auth2.authorize({
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
    'immediate': true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  console.log("handleAuthResult", new Date());
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Daca",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Update spreadsheet on user Submit",
  "browser_action": { },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "[URL which I am using]", "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "identity", "https://content-sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["[URL which I am using]"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "[my client_ID]",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: Per the MDN web docs, the "ReferenceError object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced."  It sounds like the variable, gapi, is referenced before it exists.  Your checkAuth() function references gapi in the following line of code, gapi.auth2.authorize({...}).  Where is gapi initialized?  I think you need to ensure gapi gets initialized and is assigned a value prior to calling the checkAuth() function in the onload callback.

Comment: Would the code inside the setTimeout not be better suited to go in x.onload?

Comment: could you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you fetch the gapi file using XMLHttpRequest, just fetching it will not make its code available to use. You have to load it in your background page. There are several ways to do it. For example:

The bad way (using `eval`):

```
x.onload = function() {
    if (x.status == 200) {
        eval(x.response);  //BAD WAY

        //rest of code that uses gapi ...
    }
};
```

Better way (using `<script>` tag):

```
x.onload = function() {
    if (x.status == 200) {
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.innerHTML = x.response;
        document.body.appendChild(myScript);

        //rest of code that uses gapi...
    }

};
```

In any case, no code that uses `gapi` will work until the `onload` function (which is asynchronous) finishes, so you may want to include all your related code inside that function or re-structure your code.

Comment: I used both the responses mentioned by you. But unable to proceed.

Comment: @AanshiGandhi I've just edited the code. Try the second block of code.